# three.jsで表現したパーティクルの集合図形を整列させたい。

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

以下のURLにあるように、スクロールしたらパーティクルが集合し、図形を表現する動きを実装しています。

[リンク](http://penqe.com/temp/sample.html)

コード内にもありますが、集合する図形の座標情報はstlの３dデータをblenderという3d編集ソフトを使用してjsonデータに変換したものを読み込んでいます。
しかし、こちらの座標情報だと頂点座標しか格納されていないために、パーティクルで表現するとパーティクルの密度がバラバラになってしまい、いまいちよくわからなくなってしまいます。
以下のサイトのようにパーティクルの間隔を均一に表現したいのですが何か方法はありますでしょうか。

[参考サイト](http://www.recruit-mp.co.jp/recruit/)

ちなみに、スクロールして一番はじめに生成される図形は以下の画像にあります図形をよみこんでいます。

[image: 読み込んでいる３dデータの画像]

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/127174